# Building on Team Foundation Services and Testing in Azure?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, azure, tfs, azure-devops

I'd like to run some integration tests in Azure.  I can't run these in TFServices because they require a database.  I'm wondering if it would be possible to push my project up to TFS, have TFS build the solution and push it to Azure, and then have Azure run some tests against a test database before committing it to production.  Any failures along the pipeline populate back to visual studio.  Is this even remotely possible?

Answer (score 1):

> if it would be possible to push my project up to TFS, have TFS build
>   the solution and push it to Azure

Yes, this is possible.

> and then have Azure run some tests against a test database before
>   committing it to production

Well, this is not possible.

> Any failures along the pipeline populate back to visual studio

And this is in a dream world. The only viable resolution is to have work items created out from test fails. But `populate back to Visual Studio` is a dream.

Going back to `have Azure run some tests against a test database before committing to production`.

What exactly is the issue you face when you want to run integration tests from TF Services? is this just an SQL Azure Firewall issue or something else? Have you even tried it? What was the result? If it is just a Firewall issue you most probably can mitigate by using some custom code in test initialization phase - like disabling firewall for the SQL Azure server, then enabling it again on test tear down phase.